# Satisfying Return Requirents for Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I am relatively new and I have the following code, I would like to know how to make is so I can return the temp variable while satisfying the requirement of returns for java. I want the temp to be returned but being it within the if-else block it technically isn't initialized outside of it. Not sure how to go about this

```
public String put(String id, String name) {
String temp;
    for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
        if (!(ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
            if (ids.length<10){
                ids[ids.length]=id;
                names[names.length] = name;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("There are too many members in the collection");
        }
        else 

            if ((ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = name;
                return temp;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize your `temps` attribute with `null or empty,` then return it in then end of your method not in the else block :

```
public String put(String id, String name) {
    String temp = null;//initialize your attribute with null or "" empty 
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (!(ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
            if (ids.length < 10) {
                ids[ids.length] = id;
                names[names.length] = name;
            } else {
                System.out.println("There are too many members in the collection");
            }
        } else if ((ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
            temp = names[i];
            names[i] = name;
        }
    }
    //return temp in the end if it not changes i the else block it return null or ""
    return temp;
}
```

So if the `temp` is not changes it return `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can return null by default, this means it will return if findst the value, else null:

```
public String put(String id, String name) {
String temp;
    for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
        if (!(ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
            if (ids.length<10){
                ids[ids.length]=id;
                names[names.length] = name;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("There are too many members in the collection");
        }
        else 

            if ((ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = name;
                return temp;
            }
    }
    //If the code reaches here
    //This means it couldn't find the value
    return null;
}
```

or a cleaner way:

```
public String put(String id, String name) {
    String temp = null;
    for (int i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
        if (!(ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
            if (ids.length<10){
                ids[ids.length]=id;
                names[names.length] = name;
            } else {
                System.out.println("There are too many members in the collection");
            }
        } else {
            if ((ids[i].equalsIgnoreCase(id))) {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (temp == null) {
        System.out.println("Temp value could not found");
    }
    return temp;
}
```